# How can I determine how long an FBX asset takes to process in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I'm trying to figure out how long a single FBX file takes to import and and process in Unity. How can I see the time it takes from each step?

Comment: There is no ability for us, as users of Unity, to either know, compute, guess, or display that information. ***Roughly speaking*** the more verticies your model has the longer it will take.

Comment: You could use [Resources.LoadAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html), check the `progress` and calculate yourselve an estimate how much time it will take to get to 100%...